# DocumentClass option not running

Tags: options

Sorry in advance for maybe noonish question.

I have the following [template files](http://ele.uri.edu/info/thesis/dist/thesis.zip) provided by my University. In the document class, there should be an option *oneref* that allows for all of the references to be compiled on a single file at the end of the document instead of at the end of each chapter ~ but this document option isn't working.

I've tracked down the function that initiates this behavior to the *urithesis.cls* file and option declaration `\DeclareOption{oneref}{\@wantchapterreftrue}`, but it looks like the option decision from the main *thesis.tex* file is not getting passed to this function.

New-ish to LaTeX, so again, apologize if it's obvious and thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't use external links (that could break in the future, making the question useles for other people) and provide the relevant parts of the code here directly.

Comment: Welcome. // Looks like you should report this trouble to your university.

Comment: The class redefines various internal latex commands. This worked until texlive 2019 but broke in texlive 2020. Report it to the template maintainer.